# Is it expected behavior when a Windows 8.1 iso file says Unknown Publisher?

Tags: windows-8.1, security, download, iso-image, security-warning

Using a Windows 10 PC, I downloaded Windows 8.1 iso using a link from here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows8ISO

in order to re-install Windows 8.1 on another machine.

When I right-click the file, and choose: burn disc image, I get the warning that says:

> Open file - Security warning
>
> Do you want to open this file?
>
> Name:        (path and file name)
>
> Publisher: Unknown Publisher
>
> Type:          Disc Image File
>
> From:         C:\users(path download is saved to)
>
> Open      Cancel

I was surprised at this appearing and it saying "Unknown Publisher".
Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is expected.

ISO files do not contain data indicating publisher and version information in the same way that executables do.

The problem you have is that the file has come from the Internet, and your computer is making sure that you are aware that doing things using system programs and files from the Internet is at your own risk so you need to make sure you downloaded the right file.

The computer, upon trying to burn that file, is querying it in the same way it would an executable and finding no publisher data, which is entirely expected. It is then simply showing you what it *can* see for you to be sure about what you are doing.

If you downloaded the file from a reputable source (Microsoft) and you're sure it is the right file then it's as safe as any other.

Answer (score 0):

A method to avoid the "unknown publisher" headache is by unblocking the
file from its properties.

To do so, right-click the file and select Properties.
In the General tab, next to the option that reads
"This file came from another computer and might be blocked to help protect this computer", check the "Unblock" checkbox.

Presto, no more warning messages.